# Windows 8 mount issue

Tags: windows-8, mount, iso-image

I have Windows 8 which has a mount option for .iso files, but I cannot get it to work.

I select my .iso, click the mount button, the little wheel spins, and nothing more. What can I do to get this working?

Comment: Perhaps you have a corrupted ISO?

Answer (score 0):

You can download [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/download.htm) and try it out to see if it's the ISO that's bad.